# Using RTTI with plain old structures (gcc)

Tags: c++, rtti

I need to "attach" to an external ( non modifiable ) struct some sort of RTTI information.

As I have seen from the gcc implementation, struct's with virtual methods have additionally at their beginning a pointer to a struct related to the type_info.

So my need would be to operate on those external structures by using a double pointer that has both parts: the data pointer and the "type" pointer. That double pointer has all the information of a "normal" RTTI structure. Do you know of any "legal" or hacky way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a smart pointer class for that:

```
#include <typeindex>
#include <type_traits>

// minimal implementation
template<typename T>
class RTTIPointer
{
    T* ptr_;
    std::type_index type_;
public:
    template<typename U, typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<U*, T*>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    RTTIPointer(U* p) :
        ptr_(p),
        type_(typeid(*p))
    {

    }

    // typename std::add_lvalue_reference<T>::type instead of T&
    // to support void pointers
    typename std::add_lvalue_reference<T>::type operator*() const
    {
        return *ptr_;
    }

    T* operator->() const
    {
        return ptr_;
    }

    T* get() const
    {
        return ptr_;
    }

    std::type_index type() const
    {
        return type_;
    }
};

struct Base { int a; };
struct Derived : Base { int b; };

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Derived b;
    b.a = 2;
    b.b = 3;
    RTTIPointer<Base> r(&b);
    std::cout << r->a << "\n" << r.type().name() << "\n";
    RTTIPointer<void> q(&b);
    std::cout << r.type().name() << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
2
7Derived
7Derived
```

Comment: Why `type_index` but no comparison? Usually `type_info` is kept as the value type and `type_index` just adds `operator<` to it.

Comment: @milleniumbug Thanks a lot, it was the kind of information I was looking for. ( by the way where should I had to read about it officially ? ).

Comment: @milleniumbug I tried to use as I would like but there are some problems. Please see the code bellow to substitute partly the one you shown:                                                                 struct Base { int a=0x1
 void p(){ std::cout<<a<<std::endl;}
};

struct Derived : Base { 
 int b=0x2; 
 void p(){
  std::cout<<a<<" "<<b<<std::endl;
 }
};
  
int main()
{  Base a;a.a=6;
  Derived b;b.a = 7;b.b = 8;
    
  RTTIPointer<Base> ra(&a);
  RTTIPointer<Derived> rb(&b);

  ra->p();
  rb->p();

  rb.type_=ra.type_;
  
  rb->p(); // I need to get it behave differently now !
}

Comment: @GeorgeKourtis The smart pointer class I written provides only access to RTTI info, which isn't much. It seems you are looking for something different - you need to use type erasure. Either you'll need to write a class for this manually (I'll elaborate about it later) or use something like Boost.TypeErasure.